# Macro works in Excel 2003, not in 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have a macro that exports a workbook, which works perfectly fine (and has for years) under Excel 2003. However, it doesn't work on any machine with 2007 or 2010. It runs and opens the `Save As` box, however no matter what I type, when I click ok, it just sits there. Clicking `Ok` to save doesn't do anything. Can someone help please?

The code:

```
Sub ExportReports()

Dim fdialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varfile As String

Static varfile_name As String
Dim curr_wb_name As String
Dim num_sheets As Integer
Dim xflag As String
Dim openflag As Boolean
Static strpassword As String


'check to see if invoice has been moved
'check to see if all programs report has been moved
'move specified report


'User selects the file containing the budget - must be in set format
'Changes to the format of budget spreadsheet are likely to affect this code

curr_wb_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
prog_name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("F14")

lineselectfile: 
Set fdialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fdialog
    .Title = "Please select or create the file you wish to export reports to"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel Files", "*.xlsx"

    If .Show = True Then
        varfile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    Exit Sub
        'MsgBox "You must select a file to import, please try again", _
        '        vbOKOnly, "Import Error!"
        'GoTo lineselectfile
    End If
End With

If strpassword = "" Then
   strpassword = InputBox("Enter a password to protect worksheets in this file")
End If

n = 0
For n = 1 To Workbooks.Count
   If Workbooks(n).Name = varfile_name Then
     openflag = True
     Workbooks(n).Activate
   End If
Next

If openflag = False Then
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=varfile, UpdateLinks:=0
End If

varfile_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
num_sheets = Workbooks.Count
'n = 0
xflag = "a"
'Do Until n = num_sheets
If Sheets(1).Name = "Invoice" Then
   xflag = xflag & "b"
End If
If Sheets(2).Name = "All Programs" Then
   xflag = xflag & "c"
End If
'n = n + 1
'Loop

Select Case xflag
Case "a" ' Both Invoice and All Programs must be exported
    Windows(curr_wb_name).Activate
    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Sheets("Invoice").Copy before:=Workbooks(varfile_name).Sheets(1)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strpassword, Scenarios:=True
    Range("a1").Select
    Windows(curr_wb_name).Activate
    Sheets("Preview All Programs").Select
    Sheets("Preview All Programs").Copy before:=Workbooks(varfile_name).Sheets(2)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Preview All Programs").Name = "All Programs"
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strpassword, Scenarios:=True
    Range("a1").Select
Case "ab" ' Only All Programs must be exported
    Windows(curr_wb_name).Activate
    Sheets("Preview All Programs").Select
    Sheets("Preview All Programs").Copy After:=Workbooks(varfile_name).Sheets(2)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Preview All Programs").Name = "All Programs"
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strpassword, Scenarios:=True
    Range("a1").Select
Case "ac" ' Only invoice must be exported
    Windows(curr_wb_name).Activate
    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Sheets("Invoice").Copy After:=Workbooks(varfile_name).Sheets(1)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strpassword, Scenarios:=True
    Range("a1").Select

End Select
    Windows(curr_wb_name).Activate
    Sheets("Preview").Select
    Sheets("Preview").Copy After:=Workbooks(varfile_name).Sheets(2)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Preview").Name = prog_name
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strpassword, Scenarios:=True
    Range("a1").Select
    Windows(curr_wb_name).Activate
    Worksheets("Menu").Activate
    'Workbooks(varfile_name).Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Lot of code there, but only one thing jumps out regarding changes in Excel 2007.  In 2003, if you copied a sheet to another location, it used to become the ActiveSheet.  That *doesn't* happen in 2007+, so you need to re-work your code to explicitly reference the copy.

Eg:

```
Dim shtCopy as Worksheet

'copy a sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Thisworkbook.Sheets("Data")
'get a reference to the copy
Set shtCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Thisworkbook.Sheets("Data").Index+1)
```

Edit: do you realy mean this

```
num_sheets = Workbooks.Count
```

and not

```
num_sheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
```

?

EDIT: best I can guess this should work for you

```
Sub ExportReports()

    Static varfile_name As String
    Static strpassword As String

    'Dim fdialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim varfile As String
    Dim prog_name As String
    Dim curr_wb As Workbook
    Dim selected_wb As Workbook

    Dim xflag As String
    Dim n As Integer

    Set curr_wb = ActiveWorkbook
    prog_name = curr_wb.Worksheets("Menu").Range("F14")

    'Set fdialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Please select or create the file you wish to export reports to"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
        If .Show = True Then
            varfile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    If strpassword = "" Then
       strpassword = InputBox("Enter a password to protect worksheets in this file")
    End If

    'tw Not sure what the purpose of this is?
    '  by default it will select the *previous* selected wb...
    For n = 1 To Application.Workbooks.Count
       If Workbooks(n).Name = varfile_name Then
         Set selected_wb = Workbooks(n)
         Exit For 'break out of loop
       End If
    Next

    If selected_wb Is Nothing Then
       Set selected_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=varfile, UpdateLinks:=0)
    End If

    varfile_name = selected_wb.Name
    xflag = "a"
    If selected_wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Invoice" Then
       xflag = xflag & "b"
    End If
    If selected_wb.Sheets(2).Name = "All Programs" Then
       xflag = xflag & "c"
    End If

    Select Case xflag
    Case "a" ' Both Invoice and All Programs must be exported

        CopySheet curr_wb.Sheets("Invoice"), _
                  selected_wb, 1, "", strpassword

        CopySheet curr_wb.Sheets("Preview All Programs"), _
                  selected_wb, 2, "All Programs", strpassword

    Case "ab" ' Only All Programs must be exported

        CopySheet curr_wb.Sheets("Preview All Programs"), _
                  selected_wb, 3, "All Programs", strpassword

    Case "ac" ' Only invoice must be exported

        CopySheet curr_wb.Sheets("Invoice"), _
                  selected_wb, 2, "", strpassword

    End Select

    CopySheet curr_wb.Sheets("Preview"), _
                  selected_wb, 3, prog_name, strpassword


    curr_wb.Activate
    curr_wb.Worksheets("Menu").Activate

    'selected_wb.Close

End Sub

'Copy sheet to specific position, convert to values,
'  change name
Sub CopySheet(wsToCopy As Worksheet, destWb As Workbook, _
              destPos As Integer, newName As String, pw As String)
    Dim shtCopy As Worksheet

    If destPos = 1 Then
        wsToCopy.Copy Before:=destWb.Sheets(1)
    Else
        wsToCopy.Copy After:=destWb.Sheets(destPos - 1)
    End If
    With destWb.Sheets(destPos)
        .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
        If Len(newName) > 0 Then .Name = newName
        .Protect Password:=pw, Scenarios:=True
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The person who did for us left years ago, and noone really know anything about code. Where in the code would i put your suggestion to see if it works?

Comment: @user: if you want to send me the workbook I will try to fix it for you. t i m j w i l l i a m s {at} g ma i l {.com}

Comment: Appreciate the thought but i cant do that due to confidentiality reasons. I tried taking all the sensitive information out, but 90% of the content is linked via other workbooks/budgets/database and if i take it out, the whole thing just errors out and doesnt work.

Comment: +1 agree with Issun, nice job. @user1096768, you can break the links to all your input workbooks via Data .. Edit Links, this may make it easier to sanitise your workbook for posting

Comment: Thanks for the effort, it is greatly appreciated. 
I copied in the edited code, and same thing.
No error or anything, just when i click on "ok" in the save box it doesnt do anything. Can click it 10 times and nothing, just have to cancel to get out of it.  Any other ideas?  thanks again tho!

Comment: When you say "save box", do you mean file dialog?  Works fine for me, but I only tried opening an existing file, not creating a new one. Try Setting a breakpoint in the code, and then step through it.  otherwise, I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea what file dialog is. But by Save box, i mean Windows Explorer Save As window (where you can hunt through folders to find the directory you want to save to) and then click "ok" to save the file. Clicking "ok" doesnt do anything. very odd.

Comment: File dialog is what `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`  launches: it's how you select the file into which you want to copy the sepecified worksheets.  Works fine for me: I have no idea what's going on with your setup.