# How do I make the application.reminder event work?

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I have this code in a class module - as stated to on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870058.aspx) and on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497523/macro-works-in-2003-wont-work-in-2007)

```
Public WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objReminders = Application.Reminders
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    Call Send_Email_Using_VBA
    MsgBox ("Litigate!") 
End Sub
```

I have tried using the code at the bottom of [this thread](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35985) and that won't launch either.

All I can get is outlook's reminders popup. No breakpoints are ever hit, the Msgbox never shows - even if I remove the function call. I have restarted it several times and I have no result.

Am I missing something important?

Comment: [This related link from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/ea119a5f-cdff-4c00-8c50-826a0630c8bb/) might also help.

Comment: I added `handles objReminders.Reminders` (then tried `objReminders.Application.Reminders`) It just highlights the word `handles` and tells me "Expected: End of Statement."

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? What is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `WithEvents` to handle your `Reminder` events on the `objReminders` object, but you are not declaring the subs to match. In my code below, please note the `objReminders_...` vs. your `Application_...` subs.

I played with your code in Outlook 2003 (I do not have Office 2007, so I cannot test there), and came up with the following:

```
Public WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub objReminders_Snooze(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    Call Send_Email_Using_VBA
    MsgBox ("Litigate!")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objReminders = Outlook.Reminders
End Sub
```

Implemented with this in a normal code module:

```
Sub test()

Dim rmd As New ReminderClass

rmd.objReminders.Item(1).Snooze 1 'Triggers objReminders_Snooze in class module
rmd.objReminders.Item(2).Snooze 1

End Sub
```

Now, this is triggering on the `Snooze` event, which I explicitly call. However, this should also work for you to trigger when the event first comes up (this does not, as far as I can tell, trigger when a reminder wakes from a `Snooze`). I did not have any reminders set up to test - if you have difficulties beyond this, I will set up a few of my own tests with regard to that.

```
Private Sub objReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    Call Send_Email_Using_VBA
    MsgBox ("Litigate!")
End Sub
```

---

**Update:**

After playing around with this in 2010, I found the following to work (at least fire, but it seemed to constantly fire):

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    Call Send_Email_Using_VBA
    MsgBox ("Litigate!")
End Sub
```

This was set up in the `ThisOutlookSession` object module. Does adding this do anything for you?

Comment: It didn't work. I tested both of them. (Using 2007 if that makes any difference)

Comment: What did not work? Was there an error (compile- or run-time), or a silent run? Did you have reminders to be able to snooze? Did you correct `Dim rmd As New ReminderClass` to match your own class name? The Office version *may* have an impact, but in a quick search I found nothing definitive either way. In your class module, once you have declared `Public WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.Reminders`, you should be able to select `objReminders` in the left drop-down at the top of the code window. Do that, then look at the options on the right. If they do not match my code, use what you see.

Comment: No errors. No breakpoints hit. Fixed the naming - didn't realize it was referring to the class I had. But it's still not working. Tested having the test() function in both the class module and a normal module.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce on my machine (again, 2003 not 2007), so I'm not sure what else might be causing this to not work. Did the `Snooze` action work at least, even if it did not trigger the event handling?

Comment: No, it did not. _(sorry for the delay, I posted this question on the last day before vacation, and currently have a bigger issue to fix)_

Comment: It did nothing. Is it possible my workplace has these disabled?

Comment: I suppose it is possible. I was prompted myself to enable macros (and had to in order to get this to work in 2010), but I was able to do this easily. Are you able to manually step through a test sub using `<F8>`? If so, I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I mean the events. Macros run fine when I initiate them myself.

Comment: I particularly like the update to the answer, which explains that the code snippet can go in the ThisOutlookSession module. (In my VBA IDE for Outlook, this means under Project1 > Microsoft Outlook Objects > ThisOutlookSession. That's what I tested, and it works as described.)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that this must be in the ThisOutlookSession code, not a different module

```
Private Sub objReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    Call Send_Email_Using_VBA
    MsgBox ("Litigate!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual ANSWER to this question is the following:
If you are setting recurring appointments, and putting code in the Application_Reminder event on an appointment, the Reminder event will NOT fire unless you specifically set a Reminder period in the drop down within the Appointment itself.

I played with this for days, the event would never fire unless it was a single Appointment - recurring never worked.

Setting a recurring appointment with a Reminder time of 5 minutes and all is working perfectly.

FYI here is some code that I use to send user information (self password reset) reminders on a monthly basis, using email templates stored in a local folder. Works perfectly now. Remember to create your own new category if sending auto-emails called something linke 'Send Mail'. Each appointment must be set to this category and is checked within the Sub.

```
    Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
      Dim objMsg As MailItem

       On Error Resume Next


    'IPM.TaskItem to watch for Task Reminders
    If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Item.Categories <> "Send Mail" Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

     'Check which Template for Reminder we need to send by looking for the keyword in the Reminder Appointment

If InStr(Item.Subject, "e-Expenses Password Resets") > 0 Then
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Reminder Emails\e-Expenses Resetting your own password.oft")

ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "e-Learning Password Resets") > 0 Then
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Reminder Emails\e-Learning Resetting your own password.oft")

ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "EMIS Password Resets") > 0 Then
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Reminder Emails\EMIS Web Resetting your own password.oft")

ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "NHS email Password Resets") > 0 Then
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Reminder Emails\NHS Net eMail Resetting your own password.oft")

ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "STRATA Password Resets") > 0 Then
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Reminder Emails\STRATA Resetting your own password.oft")

ElseIf InStr(Item.Subject, "VPN Password String Resets") > 0 Then
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Reminder Emails\VPN Resetting your own password.oft")

Else: Exit Sub

End If

 'Location is the email address we send to, typically to ALL users
  objMsg.To = Item.Location
  objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject  'Make the subject of the Appointment what we want to say in the Subject of the email
  objMsg.Send


  Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Have fun.

Dave Thomas